# JQuery: trigger internal link in scrollable div

Tags: jquery, scrollable

There is a div element contains following code,

```
<div id="divScroller" style="height:200px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid red;">

Record Line No. 1 <br/>
Record Line No. 2 <br/>
Record Line No. 3 <br/>
Record Line No. 4 <br/>
Record Line No. 5 <br/>

 </div>

<button id="btnAddRecords">Add Records</button>
```

There is jQuery Code to add records in that div.

var iIndex=6;

```
$("#btnAddRecords").click(function(){

        if(iIndex<200)
        {                   

            $( "#divScroller" ).append(" Record Line No. "+iIndex+" <br/>");
            iIndex++;
            $( "#divScroller" ).append(" Record Line No. "+iIndex+" <br/>");
            iIndex++;
            $( "#divScroller" ).append(" Record Line No. "+iIndex+" <br/>");
            iIndex++;
            $( "#divScroller" ).append("<a href='#' id='link_"+iIndex+"'>Record "+iIndex+" Internal Link </a><br/>");
            $('#link_"+iIndex+"').trigger('click');
            iIndex++;


        }   

});
```

I am trying to trigger the internal link while appending the records. But trigger function is working.

Will you please guide me the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If there is ordinary link with the URL within just use it for nvaigation:
`window.location.href = $('your-link-selector').attr('href');`

Answer (score 0):

Your selector and the placing of qoutes is bit wrong in your code below:

```
$('#link_"+iIndex+"').trigger('click');
```

Here, `#link_"+iIndex+"` is interpreted as a single string and there is not element with that selector and hence your `click` event is not triggered.

You can do this instead:

```
$('#link_' + iIndex).trigger('click');
```